Is there a way to do 'git commit' and 'git rebase --onto' in one shot?
git commit and git rebase --onto both make a separate commit, i.e. /refs/heads/master changes twice.
Is it possible to do it in one shot so that

deletes earlier commit 2ef2d17 and
there will be new commit fb65d19 or 921d9d4,
/refs/heads/master is changed only once?

In the same way that commit --amend works - the previous commit is deleted and a new commit is made in one shot.
$ git add A.txt
$ git commit -m A.txt
[master 921d9d4] A.txt
 1 file changed, 689 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 A.txt
$ git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate
* 921d9d4 (HEAD -> master) A.txt
* 48efbc2 C.txt
* 2ef2d17 A.txt
* 5ba51a1 B.txt
* 77e423c B.txt
* 83f803c A.txt

$ git rebase --onto 5ba51a1 2ef2d17 -Xtheirs
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
$ git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate
* fb65d19 (HEAD -> master) A.txt
* f2b8932 C.txt
* 5ba51a1 B.txt
* 77e423c B.txt
* 83f803c A.txt


Your git rebase command changes the ref refs/heads/master only once, at the end when the rebase is completed. It is unclear what you are asking for.

My git commit command changes the ref refs/heads/master a second time only once too. Question: Is there a way to do git commit and git rebase --onto in one shot? In such a way that I get the effect of both commands and the refs/heads/master changes only once in total.

Work on a detached head, then, when the commands are completed, reset master to the resulting HEAD.

All this sounds like an XY-problem.
